# Jenkins pipeline perfReport: Use "Expert Mode" constraints

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I know how to use the "Standard Mode" thresholds when publishing a performance report via jenkins pipelines:

```
perfReport errorFailedThreshold: 5, errorUnstableThreshold: 1, sourceDataFiles: 'result.jtl'
```

But how can I use these "Expert Mode" constraints like "Absolute Contraint"? (see screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out how to use the `perfReport` step (and any other step' in a pipeline script is to use the **Pipeline Snippet Generator** that will create the pipeline code according to your UI configuration.
This feature is crucial as the official [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/performance/#perfreport-publish-performance-test-result-report) of the step lacks some advance configuration options.

To use the snippet generator just click on the **Pipeline Syntax** link on the left side menu of your *Pipeline Job* (it wont be available in freestyle jobs), You can also navigate to that page using the following URL: <Your_Project_URL>/pipeline-syntax/
Once in the page select the `perfReport` step, the UI configuration of the plugin will be presented, configure it how you want and click the **Generate** button at the button of the page, that will give you the relevant pipeline code for execution the step with the relevant parameters you have configured.

Here are some examples for configuration:
*Expert Mode with Absolute Constraint*

```groovy
perfReport constraints: [absolute(escalationLevel: 'INFORMATION', meteredValue: 'AVERAGE', operator: 'NOT_GREATER', relatedPerfReport: 'result.xml', success: false, value: 0)],
filterRegex: '', modeEvaluation: true, showTrendGraphs: true, sourceDataFiles: ''
```

*Expert Mode with Relative Constraint*

```groovy
perfReport constraints: [relative(escalationLevel: 'INFORMATION', meteredValue: 'AVERAGE', operator: 'NOT_GREATER', previousResultsBlock: previous(value: 'BASELINE'), relatedPerfReport: 'results.xml', success: false, tolerance: 0.0)],
filterRegex: '', modeEvaluation: true, showTrendGraphs: true, sourceDataFiles: ''
```